# SQL: Use SET operator to get a count result

Tags: sql, oracle, set-operations

I'm trying to get a count result using a SET operator in SQL Developer.

I have to find how many of "attribute1" are in "table_name1" but are not in "table_name2"

Essentially I want the result that I would get from the following query, but using a SET operator.

```
SELECT count(distinct <attribute1>)
FROM <table_name1>
WHERE <attribute1> IS NOT (SELECT <attribute1>
                           FROM <table_name2>);
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use a set operator, then you can solve this using `MINUS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)                      -- use COUNT(DISTINCT attribute1) to avoid
FROM                                 -- duplicates
(
    SELECT attribute1
    FROM table_name1
    MINUS
    SELECT attribute1
    FROM table_name2
) t
```

However, I would probably use a `LEFT JOIN` here because it's conceptually simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.attribute1) -- replace with COUNT(*) to count duplicates
FROM table_name1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_name2 t2
    ON t1.attribute1 = t2.attribute1
WHERE t2.attribute1 IS NULL          -- indicates that attribute does NOT appear in
                                     -- the second table
```

Comment: I have to use a SET operator.  LEFT JOIN isn't a SET Operator.

Comment: @user4824195 I updated my answer, you can use `MINUS` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution:

```
SELECT count(distinct <attribute1>)
FROM <table_name1>
WHERE <attribute1> NOT IN (SELECT <attribute1>
                           FROM <table_name2>);
```

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: I have to use a SET operator. Not a relational operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(<attribute1>)
FROM <table_name1>
WHERE <attribute1> MINUS (SELECT <attribute1>
                           FROM <table_name2>);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators005.htm

Updated answer

```
SELECT COUNT(X.id_num)
(SELECT id_num
FROM Tree 
WHERE id_num)
MINUS 
(SELECT id_num 
FROM Bird) AS X
```

Comment: We don;t need to use DISTINCT as MINUS returns only DISTINCT result set

Comment: This returns an error message - INVALID Relational Operator.

Comment: Can you share your exact query and the error you received ?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id_num)
FROM Tree
WHERE id_num MINUS (SELECT id_num
                                      FROM Bird);

Comment: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator. Error at Line: 3 Column: 14

Comment: Updated answer now. Could you please try again ?

Comment: You are still missing a `from` clause and you can't use `as` for a table alias in Oracle. Look at Tim's answer to see what the correct syntax is.